# Extract only date from datetime format stored in database

Tags: codeigniter

In controller, I have stored the date as datatime format in database. In my view page I need to display only date without time. So how can can I extract only date from database?

Please give me a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the datetime variable from the database and then use

```
.ToShortDateString(), or .ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

In your view page use

```
<?php echo date('d',strtotime($your_date_variable));?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$date = '2014-02-22 03:09:00';
$createDate = new DateTime($date);
$strip = $createDate->format('Y-m-d');
var_dump($strip); // string(10) "2014-02-22"
$now = new DateTime();
$difference = $now->diff($createDate, true);
var_dump($difference);
```

Comment: He uses Codeigniter (php), not java